# Display Image from clicked item of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get the image string from the recyclerview, that is already populated, so that I can display the image on the imageview of another activity. Here, I get the path(url) of image using jsoup:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                for(Element e : document.select("img[src]"))
                {
                    Elements imgScr = e.select("img[src]");
                    String elements = imgScr.attr("src");
                    String text = imgScr.attr("alt");
                    String desc = imgScr.attr("title");

                    arrayList.add(new FeedItem(text, elements, desc));
                }
```

into `elements` variable and then storing it into arraylist. I want to get that path(url) of image(stored in `elements`) so that I can display that image in another activity. I tried to retrieve that url from the `arrayList` using this method:

```
public String getImageUrl(int pos)
    {
        return arrayList.get(pos).getThumb();
    }
```

but a `IndexOutOfBound` exception is thrown, saying that the index(pos) is invalid and size of `arrayList` is 0. I don't know why it is saying that the list has size 0, while the Recyclerview gets pouplated and shows the data which I parsed using `jsoup`. Please help me out guys, I am stuck on this for three days.

Okay the complete code is here:
This the main activity which shows the recyclerview

```
public class RestaurantsAndCafesActivity extends Activity {

public static final String URL = "http://192.168.8.102:80/jay.html";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RCRecyclerAdapter adapter;
public String imgUrl;
//public List<FeedItem> feedItemList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reyclerview_layout);

    /* Initialize RecyclerView */
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //parseResult();

    new getDataAsyncTask().execute();

    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){

                Toast.makeText(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this,"Clicked Number "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imgUrl = new getDataAsyncTask().getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this, GetReviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Imgurl" ,imgUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });
}
public class getDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
     ArrayList<FeedItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getImageUrl(int pos)
    {
        return arrayList.get(pos).getThumb();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                for(Element e : document.select("img[src]"))
                {
                    Elements imgScr = e.select("img[src]");
                    String elements = imgScr.attr("src");
                    String text = imgScr.attr("alt");
                    String desc = imgScr.attr("title");

                    arrayList.add(new FeedItem(text, elements, desc));
                }
            }
        catch(IOException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this,"Loading","Please Wait",true,false);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new RCRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

These are the adapter, viewholder and data classes:

```
public class RCRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder> {


private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
private Context mContext;

public RCRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.restaurants_cafes_layout_card, null);
    RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder mh = new RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder(v);

    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder, int i){

    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumb()
    ).error(R.drawable.placeholder).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder.thumbnail);
    RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder.title.setText(feedItemList.get(i).title);
    RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder.desc.setText(feedItemList.get(i).desc);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}
```

}

viewholder:

```
public class RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public ImageView thumbnail;
public TextView title;
public TextView desc;
//Context context;

public RCRecyclerViewListRowHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
}
```

}

data:

```
public class FeedItem {

public String title;
public String thumb;
public String desc;

public FeedItem(String title, String thumb , String desc) {
    this.title = title;
    this.thumb = thumb;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getThumb() {
    return thumb;
}
```

}

Comment: The code you posted is not enough to find the bug. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @invariant Okay I have edited the post, added the full code of the recyclerview. Please check it out.

Comment: Ok, I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
imgUrl = new getDataAsyncTask().getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
```

You're actually creating a new `AsyncTask` - if you try to get an element from the `arrayList` inside that new `AsyncTask` it's obvious the list is empty, because task populates the list within its `doInBackground()` method, and it hasn't been executed.

**Solution:**

In your onCreate method, create your `getDataAsyncTask` and keep a reference to it in a member variable.
Then, when the task finishes its execution and calls `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` set a flag indicating that fact. 
Next, in your `onClickListener`, reference **the same** task, but execute the code only if the asyncTaskFinished flag is set to true:

public class RestaurantsAndCafesActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String URL = "http://192.168.8.102:80/jay.html";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RCRecyclerAdapter adapter;
public String imgUrl;
//public List<FeedItem> feedItemList;

private getDataAsyncTask myAsyncTask;
private volatile boolean asyncTaskFinished = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reyclerview_layout);

    /* Initialize RecyclerView */
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //parseResult();

    myAsyncTask = new getDataAsyncTask();
    myAsyncTask.execute();

    ...


mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){

            if(asyncTaskFinished) {
                Toast.makeText(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this,"Clicked Number "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imgUrl = myAsyncTask.getImageUrl(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantsAndCafesActivity.this, GetReviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Imgurl" ,imgUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

In AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    adapter = new RCRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    asyncTaskFinished = true;
}
```

Please note that it is a solution that makes minimal changes in your existing code, however i would suggest a different approach - keeping the list in AsyncTask is kinda ugly, better way is to return it from doInBackground, and within onPostExecute, pass it to adapter (while not keeping a class-scope reference to it in the task), and when you need to access an element fromn the list, just reference the adapter, not your AsyncTask:

```
imgUrl = adapter.getList().get(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)).getThumb();
```

Comment: Thanks @invariant, you were right, the list was empty at `doInBackground()`. I simply used another `ArrayList` and equated it to the `arrayList` in `onPostExeute()` method and then used it to get the `url`.